# python re split string by alpha digit and symbol

Tags: python, regex

Original string is like `'asdf123Acx*23 #'` (there is a space before '#' at the end, and all chars are ascii)

I want it to be splited to

```
['asdf','123','Acx','*','23',' #']
```

How can I do it using re in python 3.4?

Comment: Go to regex101.com and give it an attempt and then Ctrl-S it and put the link here so we can see what you have tried and help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will match either alpha characters, or digits, or symbols in a row.

```
>>> s =  'asdf123Acx*23 #'
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+|\W+', s)
['asdf', '123', 'Acx', '*', '23', ' #']
```

You can check it [here](http://regexr.com/3arp8). Use that website to train!

Comment: Thank you. But is there anything like \d to digit , can represent symbols, cause there are 33 kinds of symbols I need to handle

Comment: Forgot to tag you @circleone

Comment: @Docteur you don't need to use capturing groups.

Comment: Note that `[^\w]+` would be written as `\W+`

Comment: It seems I have much moer to get in my head; thank you again, @AvinashRaj ; added